# Fetch Invoices from Quickbooks (with the help of API) using PHP

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

Here is my scenario.

1. There will be a company having business account on QuickBooks.
2. Company will add Customers/Clients/Users to their account.
3. Now the company will issue invoices to these Customers/Clients/Users.
4. I have to show (list) the invoices generated by company and I will pass CustomerID (ClientID/UserID) as a parameter to get invoices for that Customer/User/Client only.

Note that the companies will provide us their credentials in order to fetch invoices of their Customers/Clients/Users.
I just have to show the invoices, I don't have to do anything else with Quickbooks or Quickbooks API.
Also note that I have fetch invoices from Quickbooks Online and the Desktop version (using Web connector).

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are building a SaaS service (e.g. you are charging your customers a monthly fee to connect their QuickBooks to your app) then you can do this using **IPP/IDS**.
If you are not charging them a monthly fee, then you can do this with the **Web Connector/qbXML**.

Regardless of which connection type you go for, this doesn't make any sense:

> 1. I have to show (list) the invoices generated by company and I will pass CustomerID (ClientID/UserID) as a parameter to get invoices for
>      that Customer/User/Client only.

The OAuth tokens/connections are QuickBooks-company-file-specific, and there is no such field "CustomerID" (or "ClientID", or "UserID").

**For a SaaS/IPP/IDS example**, download this:

- http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/

And look at these scripts:

- docs/example_ipp_config.php
- docs/example_ipp_oauth.php
- docs/example_ipp_ids_5.php

You'll have to register here to get your own OAuth tokens:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0005_introduction_to_quickbooksapi/the_developers_experience

The docs/example_ipp_ids_5.php script shows how to fetch all customers. You can change it to use QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice to fetch all invoices instead.

Your code will end up looking something like this:

```
$Service = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();

$perpage = 3;
for ($page = 1; $page <= 3; $page++)
{
    print('PAGE ' . $page . "\n\n");

    $list = $InvoiceService->findAll($Context, $realm, null, $page, $perpage);

    foreach ($list as $Invoice)
    {
        print('Internal ID [' . $Invoice->getId() . ' => ' . $Invoice->getHeader()->getDocNumber() . ']' . "\n\n");
    }

    print("\n\n\n");
}
```

**For a Web Connector example (QuickBooks desktop)** download this:

- http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/

And look at this example:

- docs/example_web_connector_import.php

And the quick-start guide:

- [QuickBooks PHP Quick-Start](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start)

You'll end up with something similar to:

```
/**
 * Build a request to import invoices already in QuickBooks into our application
 */
function _quickbooks_invoice_import_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    // Iterator support (break the result set into small chunks)
    $attr_iteratorID = '';
    $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Start" ';
    if (empty($extra['iteratorID']))
    {
        // This is the first request in a new batch
        $last = _quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action);
        _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action);           // Update the last run time to NOW()

        // Set the current run to $last
        _quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $last);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a continuation of a batch
        $attr_iteratorID = ' iteratorID="' . $extra['iteratorID'] . '" ';
        $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Continue" ';

        $last = _quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action);
    }

    // Build the request
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <InvoiceQueryRq ' . $attr_iterator . ' ' . $attr_iteratorID . ' requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <MaxReturned>' . QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAX_RETURNED . '</MaxReturned>
                    <ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
                        <FromModifiedDate>' . $last . '</FromModifiedDate>
                    </ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
                    <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                </InvoiceQueryRq>   
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

/** 
 * Handle a response from QuickBooks 
 */
function _quickbooks_invoice_import_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   
    if (!empty($idents['iteratorRemainingCount']))
    {
        // Queue up another request

        $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_INVOICE, null, QB_PRIORITY_INVOICE, array( 'iteratorID' => $idents['iteratorID'] ));
    }

    // This piece of the response from QuickBooks is now stored in $xml. You 
    //  can process the qbXML response in $xml in any way you like. Save it to 
    //  a file, stuff it in a database, parse it and stuff the records in a 
    //  database, etc. etc. etc. 
    //  
    // The following example shows how to use the built-in XML parser to parse 
    //  the response and stuff it into a database. 

    // Import all of the records
    $errnum = 0;
    $errmsg = '';
    $Parser = new QuickBooks_XML_Parser($xml);
    if ($Doc = $Parser->parse($errnum, $errmsg))
    {
        $Root = $Doc->getRoot();
        $List = $Root->getChildAt('QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/InvoiceQueryRs');

        foreach ($List->children() as $Invoice)
        {
            $arr = array(
                'TxnID' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet TxnID'),
                'TimeCreated' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet TimeCreated'),
                'TimeModified' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet TimeModified'),
                'RefNumber' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet RefNumber'),
                'Customer_ListID' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet CustomerRef ListID'),
                'Customer_FullName' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet CustomerRef FullName'),
                'ShipAddress_Addr1' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress Addr1'),
                'ShipAddress_Addr2' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress Addr2'),
                'ShipAddress_City' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress City'),
                'ShipAddress_State' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress State'),
                'ShipAddress_PostalCode' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress PostalCode'),
                'BalanceRemaining' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet BalanceRemaining'),
                );

            QuickBooks_Utilities::log(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, 'Importing invoice #' . $arr['RefNumber'] . ': ' . print_r($arr, true));

            foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
            {
                $arr[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            }

            // Store the invoices in MySQL
            mysql_query("
                REPLACE INTO
                    qb_example_invoice
                (
                    " . implode(", ", array_keys($arr)) . "
                ) VALUES (
                    '" . implode("', '", array_values($arr)) . "'
                )") or die(trigger_error(mysql_error()));

            // Remove any old line items
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM qb_example_invoice_lineitem WHERE TxnID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($arr['TxnID']) . "' ") or die(trigger_error(mysql_error()));

            // Process the line items
            foreach ($Invoice->children() as $Child)
            {
                if ($Child->name() == 'InvoiceLineRet')
                {
                    $InvoiceLine = $Child;

                    $lineitem = array( 
                        'TxnID' => $arr['TxnID'], 
                        'TxnLineID' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet TxnLineID'), 
                        'Item_ListID' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet ItemRef ListID'), 
                        'Item_FullName' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet ItemRef FullName'), 
                        'Descrip' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet Desc'), 
                        'Quantity' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet Quantity'),
                        'Rate' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet Rate'), 
                        );

                    foreach ($lineitem as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $lineitem[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
                    }

                    // Store the lineitems in MySQL
                    mysql_query("
                        INSERT INTO
                            qb_example_invoice_lineitem
                        (
                            " . implode(", ", array_keys($lineitem)) . "
                        ) VALUES (
                            '" . implode("', '", array_values($lineitem)) . "'
                        ) ") or die(trigger_error(mysql_error()));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

For a **QuickBooks Online via qbXML example** (QuickBooks Online) download this:

- http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/

And look at this example:

- docs/example_online_edition.php

You'll end up with something similar to:

```
// Register in DESKTOP mode to get these. Docs: 
//  http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Online_via_qbXML#Connecting_with_the_.27Desktop.27_model_of_communication
$application_id = '134476472';
$application_login = 'qboe.test.test.com';
$connection_ticket = 'TGT-47-1sRm2nXMVfm$n8hb2MZfVQ';

// Create our new gateway instance 
$Gateway = new QuickBooks_Gateway_OnlineEdition(
    $application_id,
    $application_login,
    $connection_ticket);

$xml = '<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <InvoiceQueryRq>

            </InvoiceQueryRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>';

// Send the request
$resp = $Gateway->qbxml($xml);

print($resp);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply, I have opted the "For a QuickBooks Online via qbXML example" option. I have generated application_id, application_login and the connection_ticket/Connection Key and I replaced them in "docs/example_online_edition.php" but unfortunately I am not getting any response when I browse the "docs/example_online_edition.php" using my generated values but if I keep the values same as they were (default provided by you) I get a XML response. I am not sure what have I missed.

Comment: Also note that the link 
"https://login.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/qbn/sdkapp/confirm?appid=YOUR-APPLICATION-ID-HERE&serviceid=2004&appdata=1" is not functional after I replace YOUR-APPLICATION-ID-HERE with my application id

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, finally I am able to fetch all invoices (generated in Quickbooks online) in XML format using the following xml request.
$xml = '<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><InvoiceQueryRq></InvoiceQueryRq></QBXMLMsgsRq>';

Keith, can't we filter the response? I mean currently in response of above XML request I get all invoices but what if I want to fetch only those invoices which are generated for a specific User (say TOM) only? Or what if I want to fetch UNPAID invoices only? Is there a way?

Comment: You can use the OSR (https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) for qbXML reference. Make sure to set the version to 6.0, CHECK the 'OE' checkbox, UNCHECK the 'US' checkbox, use the "Select Message" dropdown to choose your request type, and the "XML Ops" tab to view the raw XML you can send.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally I have made my solution.